# Warm blooded Desert Dwellers

Tags: xenobiology

How could a race of warm blooded, hair covered humanoids maintain their body temperature of 43.7’c when their arid homeworld has temperatures ranging from 32’c in winter and to 78’c in summer, and dropping to -3’c at night. These temperatures are due to the planets orbit which is on the innermost extreme of the habitable zone.

I apologize but I am looking for biological adaptations that the species may have developed in order to combat the extreme temperatures.

Comment: What are the daily variations of temperature?

Comment: so a little warmer than earth?

Comment: @John Earth bottoms out around -90, +32 degrees is hotter than my hometown usually gets in midsummer and that's the minimum. You could boil water with that temperature difference and have heat to spare.

Comment: @ash but earth tops out around 57 degrees, so this planet has a far narrower range than earth and is slightly warmer.

Comment: in what kind of environment? the temperature range of a planet does not tell you much about the environmental conditions.

Comment: The planet is mostly arid with small oceans, Cavnians (that’s the desert race) are widespread but mostly stick to the desert and mountainous regions.

Comment: did they evolve on this planet?

Comment: Yes, they did, they evolved from a form of desert fox.

Answer (score 4):

Being nocturnal would help, so would the common desert adaptation of [burrowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrow) since the soil temperature at depth is almost always lower than that on the surface. Burrows also keep you out of drying winds and windblown dust. In short they can minimise their heat exposure by largely living underground and only coming out at night.

In response to the current edit I'd add that the underground temperature is extremely *stable* providing protection from extremes of heat and cold. With such low overnight temperatures a [crepuscular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crepuscular_animal) behaviour pattern might be more beneficial than pure nocturnalism.

Answer (score 2):

Burrowing animals can control their environment by digging deeper. That's why many desert dwelling species live a good part of their lives underground.

While nowhere near as hot as your proposed planets, the deserts of earth are home to a large variety of both warm- and coldblooded species, ranging from insects and lizards (cold blooded) to voles, birds, foxes, and large cats (warm blooded).

Most of these will spend the hotter parts of the days either underground, in burrows, and/or seek the shade of hills and sand dunes.

The main problem with your planet's temperature range is that most biological processes that control life on earth tend to break down at the higher end of it. Proteins start breaking down at around 70C, with some breaking down earlier than that.

Comment: How could an organism evolve to prevent said breakdown?

Comment: @PrinceThomasthe42nd non-carbon based life forms might work.

Comment: So they could be silicon based life forms?

Comment: @PrinceThomasthe42nd I don't know how the body chemistry of such creatures would work, possibly.

Answer (score 0):

**Bigness.**

These things are big, and wet.  Big wet things.  Also pretty round with a low surface to volume ratio.   When it stays below their body temperature in winter they use metabolism to keep warm and they have fur to keep the warmth at night.  The fur is dry - they are wet on the inside.

In the summer their metabolism slows down.  With the inner fire stoked, their bigness and the high latent heat of water means even in the 78 degree air temperatures, they warm up slow.  They also sweat which works well in the desert because the evaporating water carries away heat.  Also these beasts are well insulated with subcutaneous fat which does not conduct heat very well.  Just as marine mammals use fat to keep warm in chilly water, your big round fat wet humanoids will use fat to slow heating of their innards in the hot hot air.

Comment: But sweat is a waste of body water which is very precious in a desert.

Comment: @PrinceThomasthe42nd - yes, if you sweat wastefully like humans do,  But I dont know another word besides "sweat".    No sweat rolling off the body because that drop is wasted.  Sweat to keep the skin wet at all time in the heat.    Maybe a sweat more like horses do.  And not a waste if it keeps you cool.

Answer (score 0):

Live mostly in the 32 deg C parts of the planet which would be like us living in a 27ish deg C part of our planet?

Air conditioning?

Live in the shade?